# Low effort questions and answers referencing a certain site

Tags: discussion, spam

Example question: [Why does the compiler may not perform inlining, if the function contains static variables?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61766649/why-does-the-compiler-may-not-perform-inlining-if-the-function-contains-static)

Lately I have seen several questions like this,  from low-rep accounts just linking to the site along with a low-effort question. And many answers where the "answer" is a link to the site (sometimes with a low effort explanation).

It seems to me this is just promotion of the site in question, rather than genuine questions and answers. I flagged as spam but the flag was declined .

Can/should anything be done about these types of questions?  To be clear, I mean site promotion thinly disguised as questions.  A similar question would be OK if it stood on its own merit .

Comment: Most spam doesn't come from users >100 rep... And honestly it's a site that frequently appears in my search results when using my favourite search engine, it wouldn't surprise me if they were legitimate inclusions from people using the site to learn

Comment: @Nick perhaps it frequently appears in search results due to promotion of the site (of which featuring it as much as possible on SO is a part)

Comment: If it's the geeksforgeeks reference, that site comes up a lot just by searching on the internet. I've landed there often while searching for tutorials. I haven't yet landed there as a result of going through Stack Overflow first. The search takes me directly to the site.

Comment: Good point, maybe if we stopped linking to w3schools it would disappear off the face of the earth too /s

Answer (score 4):

Spam is defined as unsolicited, self-promotional material. While these might be low-quality questions, they're not spam because they're not from users who are affiliated with GeeksForGeeks.

For low-quality questions, your options are:

- Downvote,
- Vote to close,
- Edit to improve.

Choose one or more.

[Scratte already nailed](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/397429/low-effort-questions-and-answers-referencing-a-certain-site#comment769973_397429) why you tend to see a lot of low-quality questions containing links to sites like GeeksForGeeks, cppreference.com, W3Schools, etc.:

> If it's the geeksforgeeks reference, that site comes up a lot just by searching on the internet. I've landed there often while searching for tutorials. I haven't yet landed there as a result of going through Stack Overflow first. The search takes me directly to the site.

Beginners (both at programming and at asking questions) often end up there, don't understand what they read or happen across something simply wrong, and then come to Stack Overflow to try to get a good answer. That's not really suspicious or sinister, and in many ways, it's behavior that we try to encourage.

Frankly, upon closer review, I don't see anything wrong with [the question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61766649/why-does-the-compiler-may-not-perform-inlining-if-the-function-contains-static) you linked, aside from some (admittedly serious) grammar issues.

Comment: "don't see anything wrong" Other than zero research.

Comment: No, not even that, @philipxy. I checked, and couldn't find any other question on Stack Overflow that was even *remotely* close to being a duplicate. The question was narrowly scoped enough to be a good fit for a Q&A site. It didn't need any additional research to narrow it down.

Comment: I wish geeksforgeeks could be edited without having an account because a lot of those pages encourage practices that could easily make your program crash or do the wrong thing.

Comment: @CodyGray I don't see why you think the question is not answered by any generic inlining question, eg ''c++ when does the compiler inline site:stackoverflow.com". Tacking on particular circumstances doesn't affect the answer. (I realize 'inline' semantics has evolved.)